# How to select a DB-driver with eclipse, JPA and maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa

I want to create a project using hibernate and hsqldb in eclipse with maven and eclipse JPA support.

I created the project as maven project, configured the pom so maven can find me the jars for hsqldb and hibernate.

Then I asked eclipse to convert the project into a JPA project.
(right-click --> Configure --> Convert to JPA project).

Everything works like magic up to the point where eclipse asks for connections, looks for hsqldb.jar which it can't find.

There are hsqldb-.jar in the maven repository, and the robust and old-fashioned way would be to configure the eclipse build path and add it as an external library.

But with maven this is obviously **not** *the right way to do it*.

So what is the right way to tell eclipse/maven/JPA where to find the jar?

Comment: First you should add the appropriate dependencies to your pom file ....

Comment: @khmarbaise Obviously so. The whole thing, including eclipse, is smokingly new installed, and the jars are in the maven repository just because they were requested by the pom. Alas, the repository is a hidden directory, and not without reason, I guess.